# How to change sql query with ruby on rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Has any one know how to change this sql query to ruby on rails query. Here joining 4 tables and using subqueries, group by and order by.

```
subquery = ProjectMilestoneReportStatus
    .group('project_milestone_id')
    .select('project_milestone_id, max(created_at) as created_at')
ProjectMilestone.joins([:milestone, :project_milestone_report_statuses])
    .joins("INNER JOIN (#{subquery.to_sql}) AS grouped_status on                            
    project_milestone_report_statuses.project_milestone_id = 
    grouped_status.project_milestone_id
    and project_milestone_report_statuses.created_at = 
    grouped_status.created_at")
    .where(project_id: project_id)
    .select('milestones.id, milestones.name, 
    project_milestone_report_statuses.status,
    project_milestones.milestone_end_date, project_milestones.id as 
    project_milestone_id')
    .order('project_milestone_report_statuses.created_at DESC')
```

The classes in question are:

```
class Milestone < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :project_milestones 
end 

class ProjectMilestone < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :milestone 
  belongs_to :project 
  has_many :project_milestone_report_statuses 
end 

class ProjectMilestoneReportStatus < ApplicationRecord 
  belongs_to :project_milestone 
end
```

Comment: can you post your model & table structures with associations?

Comment: class Milestone < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_milestones
end

class ProjectMilestone < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :milestone
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :project_milestone_report_statuses
end

class ProjectMilestoneReportStatus < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :project_milestone
end

class ProjectStatus < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :project_statuses
  has_many :project_milestones
end

Comment: Update the question with this info giving proper indentation so that everyone would get a clear view of your question.

Comment: You should read the Rails documentation about associations (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and querying (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute raw query in ruby

```
sql = "select milestones.id,foo.status,milestones.name,foo.created from project_statuses inner join projects on project_statuses.project_id=projects.id inner join project_milestones on project_milestones.project_id=projects.id inner join milestones on milestones.id=project_milestones.milestone_id inner join (SELECT project_milestone_id as id,status,created_at as created FROM project_milestone_report_statuses s1 WHERE created_at = (SELECT MAX(created_at)
FROM project_milestone_report_statuses s2
WHERE s1.project_milestone_id = s2.project_milestone_id) GROUP BY project_milestone_id,status,created_at) as foo on project_milestones.id=foo.id "

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

If you don't want to execute raw query then let me know in details about your models and associations.